# CSS negative z-index not working properly

Tags: css, html

So I am having a z-index problem on my website, take a look at: https://displee.com/osrs-store

If you look at the header of each step you, you will notice that only step 3 has a ribbon and step 1 and 2 do not (if you don't see this, then try to zoom-in). Step 1 and 2 also should have a ribbon.
I cannot seem to fix it, I played around with z-index on all elements and using position relative but it is not working. I think somehow it has to do with the height of my content or something.

Comment: if only the negative z-index has a problem. why not have all indexes as positives?

Comment: I find the "look at my site" questions lazy. You want *me* to scour your code and markup to find the issue.... rather than *you* taking the time to post relevant, reproducible code which shows your issue.

Comment: If I place the exact same code in a JSFiddle, it works, but if I put the exact same code on my website, it doesn't. Also haven't thought yet about positives indexes, but how would you manage to get a ribbon behind the header with positive indexes?

Comment: "on my website, take a look"... the link is dead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add height: 0; to my body element, then everything is fixed. Does anyone knows why this fixes it. Also, I don't think this is the right way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a stacking issue with your `.panel` elements stacking context. Your are trying to place a the `<header>`'s `:before` behind it's parent - the `.panel`.

You can't really stack an element behinds it's parent I think, you set the the `z-index` to -1 maybe trying to place the element behind it's parent but are clearly running into issues.

What you probably need to do is place the the `header:before` puesdo element next to the white content box (the `.panel`) instead of behind it by simply reducing it's size, and fixing some minor issues.

In your stylesheet (https://displee.com/css/home_style.css) update theses 2 styles starting around line 548:

CSS

```
.ribbon > header:before { /*Update selector*/
    bottom: -24px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.ribbon > header:before { /*Update selector*/
    border-color: transparent #3b4d56 transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 21px 24px 0; /*Update size*/
    height: 0;
    left: 0; /*Update to zero*/
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0; /*Update to zero*/
}
```

I see [this as the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftm0D.jpg). I believe this fixes your *having to zoom in* issue also.

Comment: The problem of this is that the ribbon is not behind the header. It should be behind the header.